# Verify that rsync copied everything it was supposed to?

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to use rsync to back up a remote Linux server

I'm running DeltaCopy as a server on my desktop PC (Win7/64), and running rsync by SSH'ing to the Linux box, sudo'ing to root, and doing something like (slightly obfuscated, for obvious reasons):

```
rsync -azv --modify-window=1 \
--exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found/*} \
--log-file=/var/log/rsync.log /* rsync://obfuscated@1.2.3.4/MyBackup
```

It seems to be working, but I'm worried that there might be one or more files that didn't get copied and are quietly falling between the cracks.

Is there any straightforward way to get rsync to generate a concise list of files on the Linux box that SHOULD have gotten copied, but either didn't get copied, or are different, so I'll know which ones need special attention (MySQL InnoDB, etc)?

Also, given the above example, what changes should I make for subsequent runs in order to replace the copy with newer versions if something has changed?

Comment: rsync will print a message on stderr if it fails to transfer a file -- is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following option:

```
--dry-run
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.  It will show what rsync would have done, but not verify that it got everything (which it would, but...).

Comment: You can also use _--checksum_ to ensure that if rsync skips a file it is based on the checksum and not just the file size and date.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rsync manual, the -v option will tell which files are gonna be copied. You could then take these filenames and create a script that runs thru both systems and perform a md5 sum. You could then diff the files and if necessary scp the files with different md5.